# Source control (SVN) best practices

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm looking for a bit of advice on using SVN (possibly not SVN specific).

We're only just getting into using Source control as the company is now starting to grow a bit (I know I know, we should have been using it anyway ;-)).

Each project has different files that you might want to exclude from source control i.e. content images, dll's files etc, but there are a few specific examples I'm not entirely sure what to do with.

1) SQL DB files - I was considering just backing these up seperately (as part of our backup routine) and then with each branch just have the developers check-in the change scripts

2) DLL's in the bin folder. I was considering only checking-in those that are part of the application and not any that should live in the GAC. Secondly, I was going to exclude any where the dll is from another local project that is itself under source control?

Any advice you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Al

Comment: I guess you will get quite a lot of conflicting answers ;) There really is no silver bullet for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About

- SQL DB files

You thinking is correct... this should be backed up separately and you can create branches to keep them.

- DLL's in the bin folder

I would assume all DLLs required for an individual project should be available with the project in the repository so that your working unit is complete.

Moreover every project should have it's own in the repository... its not advised to keep the overlapping in projects source control.

### EDIT

Own Repository meant separate `trunk`, `branches` and `tags` for each project.

Comment: At least the SVN book doesn't say anything against multiple projects in the same repository: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s04.html

Comment: @MarcusRiemer it's best to only keep related projects in the same repository, eg the app, the setup/msi/rpm builder and the unit tests but not completely unrelated projects

Comment: Ah, yes, thats true of course. I was thinking of something along the line of "visual studio projects" instead of general projects.

Comment: @MarcusRiemer You're right; I meant separate folder structure and misused word `Repository`

Answer (score 0):

For 1) there should be general "setup scripts" populating a fresh database for each revision you have in source control. Optional changescripts are fine, but make sure you can easily setup the whole database with a single step.

Backups of "live" data should not live in the repository of course.

Regarding 2), this sounds like you are doing something with .Net. In this case, I recommend to handle DLLs, as they are build dependencies, somewhere along the project files. Keep in mind that MSBuild does a good job "pulling" all required dependent assemblies when specifying project dependencies.

In my opinion, the "build" (or "bin") folder should never be checked in with any contents. Its only populated when the project has been built.

Comment: Hi Marcus - thanks for your response. One example though that throws a spanner in the works. Im working on an Umbraco site, which includes all of the DLL's as part of the project. And subsequently each time you add an umbraco package to the project there may be some new assemblies in the bin. What would you suggest here?

Comment: Isn't the bin folder only populated on building? That wouldn't be a problem at all. I would simply keep the umbraco dependencies in the subfolder of the directory where the vcproj file lives. And of course you put them under version control.

Comment: Hi Marcus - could you expand on your solution to 1). I'm trying to figure out whether I should physically be storing .mdf/.ldf files, whether they should be in the truck/branches etc? Thanks

Comment: I would treat them as "live data" and do not check them in. Instead I check in a batch file that is able to create and initially populate the database. But take this with a grain of salt: I have only worked with DB2, Postgres and Oracle databases so far, their might be a better approach for the MS SQL Servers.

Answer (score 0):

Include everything that isn't created by the build, essentially anything that is left after a `make clean`

External libs and dlls are a very good candidate for including in SVN so that if you ever upgrade those components you can always recreate an earlier version. The same with any test or sample data.

SVN efficiently only stores differences and when the files change so there is generally no problem including large amounts of static data

Comment: That's what I was thinking, so in the comment above I talked about an umbraco project. There are some assemblies that might be generated by the build action i.e. code I have written, but there are lots of assemblies that comes as part of Umbraco - I would think the latter should be checked in right?

Comment: You should be able to got to a blank machine, svn checkout and build an installer. Of course what you regard as part of the compiler/OS and what is a required lib is sometimes tricky